# Unhandled exception: Expected string literal when calling JSON.parse

Tags: json, dart

The following code throws an Unhandled exception:

```
Map map = JSON.parse("{'foo':1}");
var debug = map["foo"];
print("$debug");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter 2.5 of the [JSON specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says that:

```
string = quotation-mark *char quotation-mark
...
quotation-mark = %x22      ; "
...
```

Meaning that strings in JSON **must** look like `"..."` and `'...'` is not a valid JSON string.

The JSON parser in Dart just requires you to adhere to the specification.

Comment: You explained it very well.  Thank you.